# Swift: CoreData Conforming to MKAnnotation

Tags: swift

I am attempting to implement my custom CoreData `Carpark` entity to conform to `MKAnnotation` like how we could make a `class` object conform to `MKAnnotation`.

I adapted my implementation from the following posts: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663019/ios-swift-mapkit-why-mkpointannotation-is-draggable-while-a-class-that-conforms), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397963/saving-location-coordinates-to-core-data-swift-3?rq=1).

My implementation so far:

```
//At Carpark+CoreDataClass.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData
import Mapkit

@objc(Carpark)
public class Carpark: NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(self.lat), longitude: Double(self.long))
    }

    var title: String {
        return self.carparkName
    }

}

//At Carpark+CoreDataProperties.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData
import Mapkit

extension Carpark {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Carpark> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Carpark>(entityName: "Carpark")
    }

    @NSManaged public var carparkName: String?
    @NSManaged public var sundayAndPublicHolRate: String?
    @NSManaged public var saturdayRate: String?
    @NSManaged public var weekdayRate1: String?
    @NSManaged public var weekdayRate2: String?
    @NSManaged public var lat: Double
    @NSManaged public var long: Double
}

//At VC where I addAnnotations
var allCarparks: [Carpark]?
var nearbyCarparks = [Carpark]()
var searchedCarpark: Carpark!

func filterCarparksWithinRadius() {

    var allAnnotations = [Carpark]()

    let searchRadius = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.SearchRadius) as! Double
    let searchedCarparkLocation = CLLocation(latitude: searchedCarpark.lat, longitude: searchedCarpark.long)

    allCarparks?.forEach({ (carpark) in
        let carparkLocation = CLLocation(latitude: carpark.lat, longitude: carpark.long)
        let distance = carparkLocation.distance(from: searchedCarparkLocation)

        if distance <= searchRadius && distance != 0 {
            nearbyCarparks.append(carpark)
            allAnnotations.append(carpark)
        }
    })

    allAnnotations.append(searchedCarpark)
    mapView.addAnnotations(allAnnotations as! [MKAnnotation]) //Problem here

    let zoomCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: searchedCarpark.lat, longitude: searchedCarpark.long)
    zoomToLocation(coordinate: zoomCoordinate)

}
```

The above code would throw the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Carpark coordinate]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400009e690'

Is there a way that we could make CoreData conform to MKAnnotation like how we could do it for a class object? Similar to something like this?:

```
class Carpark: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?

    var carparkName: String?
    var lat: Double?
    var long: Double?

    init(carparkName: String?, lat: Double?, long: Double?) {
        self.title = carparkName
        self.carparkName = carparkName
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, long!)
    }
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why did you implement coordinate as it was in the question and not as it was declared in the answer in [your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663019/ios-swift-mapkit-why-mkpointannotation-is-draggable-while-a-class-that-conforms)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson because I am not setting the coordinate parameter, only lat and long. Adding the `get{}` also gave the same error message.

Comment: Ok, I thought you needed both get and set but looking closer at it set is not needed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to typecast allAnnotations when calling addAnnotations

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have to. Else it would say `Cannot convert value of type [Carpark] to expected argument type of [MKAnnotation]`

Comment: Strange, I have a similar setup in an app and I don't cast my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by setting Codegen to `Manual/None`, and properties are then accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your coordinate property public to be seen outside your module (outside like in the MapView framework). Maybe this is also the reason you need to cast your array.

This is my definition

```
public class Location: NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {

  public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
  }
  //....more code
}
```

And in my view controller I have a property

```
 var locations = [Location]()
```

And I fetch into it and adds to map view like this

```
private func updateLocations() {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(locations)

    let entity = Location.entity()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Location>()
    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    do {
        locations = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch {
        fatalCoreDataError(error)
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(locations)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have attempted your solution but it still gave the same error message.

Comment: Can you add the complete func filterCarparksWithinRadius() to your question?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code. Have you tried to access the coordinate property yourself in your code? Otherwise maybe you could add some print statements in that func, like printing carpark.coordinate and searchedCarpark.coordinate

Comment: I have attempted to access the coordinate property but somehow just unable to. It says `Value of type 'Carpark' has no member 'coordinate'`. This is seriously my worse nightmare.

Comment: So code compiles but Carpark misbehaves. Long shot but maybe Xcode has messed up, try to clean project by selecting Product->Clean and maybe also restart Xcode. I have had issues with Xcode after changing my NSManagedObject subclasses

Comment: Hi there, I managed to solve it. It was a simple and rookie mistake. I did not set Codegen to `Manual/None`.